# How to investigate defmacro* (with asterisk) error on an old emacs package

Tags: init-file, elisp-macros

I'm trying to load the [defhook](https://github.com/neil-smithline-elisp/defhook) package without success. The code defines a macro using `defmacro*` (with the asterisk at the end), and I can't find any info about it. (The fact that the '*' is ignored by search engines doesn't help either.)

The code in question is as follows:

```
(defmacro* defhook (name (hook-sym &key 
               (op 'add)
                               (interactive-spec t)
               (append nil)
               (validate-hook-name t)
                               (eval-after nil)
                               (local nil)
                               (hook-args nil))
                     &rest body)
 ...
```

And when I start Emacs with `--debug-init`, I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function defmacro*)
  (defmacro* defhook (name (hook-sym &key (op 'add) (interactive-spec t) (append nil) (validate-hook-name t) (eval-after nil) (local nil) (hook-args nil)) &rest body) "Create a hook function and add it to the appropria..." nil (progn (or (not (null defhook-user-prefix)) (cl--assertion-failed '(not (null defhook-user-prefix)) nil (list (null defhook-user-prefix)) (list))) nil) (let* ((post-hook-action t) (post-defhook-action t) (our-name (symbolp name)) (our-local local) (our-append append) (our-op (cl-assert-rtn op (member op '(add delete no-op)) t)) (our-hook-sym (defhook-check-sym-syntax hook-sym "HOOK-NAME")) (our-hook-args hook-args) (tmp-int-spec interactive-spec) (our-int-spec (if (eq tmp-int-spec t) (interactive) tmp-int-spec)) (our-val-hook-name validate-hook-name) (our-eval-after (or eval-after 'simple)) (our-hook-name (cl-assert-rtn our-hook-sym (or (not our-val-hook-name) (string-match-p "-\\(hook\\|function\\|hooks\\|functions\\)$" (symbol-name our-hook-sym))) t)) (our-func-name (defhook-create-function-name (defhook-check-sym-syntax name "NAME") our-hook-sym)) (our-func-sym (intern our-func-name)) (began-in-hook (member our-func-sym (if (boundp our-hook-sym) (symbol-value our-hook-sym) (set our-hook-sym nil)))) (our-body body) (our-docstring (if (stringp (car our-body)) (progn (setq our-docstring (car-safe ...))))) (defhook-done-form (list 'defhook-done (list 'quote our-func-sym) (list 'quote our-hook-sym) (list 'quote our-op) (list 'quote began-in-hook) ''nil (list 'quote our-hook-args)))) (if :Comment-Ignore-Test-Code nil (defhook test1 (foo-hook) (message "foo-hook-test1") (message "foo-hook-test1 again")) (defhook test2 (foo-hook) (message "foo-hook-test 2"))) (cond ((eq 'no-op our-op) defhook-done-form) ((eq 'delete our-op) (remove-hook our-hook-sym our-func-sym) defhook-done-form) (t (remove-hook our-hook-sym our-func-sym) (let ((defhook-delayed-done-form (list ... ... ... ...)) (defhook-executed-form (list ... ... ...))) (list 'let (list (list ... ...)) (list 'eval-after-load (list ... our-eval-after) (list ... ...)) (list 'defhook-done (list ... our-func-sym) (list ... our-hook-sym) (list ... our-op) (list ... began-in-hook) 'pending-load (list ... our-hook-args))))))))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-955329> nil "~/.emacs.d/org-status/defhook.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 30747
  load-with-code-conversion("~/.emacs.d/org-status/defhook.el" "~/.emacs.d/org-status/defhook.el" nil nil)
  load("~/.emacs.d/org-status/defhook.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "~/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1253
  load-with-code-conversion("~/.emacs.d/init.el" "~/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("~/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ff01aa07dd1>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ff01aa07de5>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Removing the asterisk from `defmacro` produces another error:

```
 entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (lambda (name (hook-sym &key (op 'add) (interactive-spec t) (append nil) (validate-hook-name t) (eval-after nil) (local nil) (hook-args nil)) &rest body) "Create a hook function and add it to the appropria..." (progn (or (not (null defhook-user-prefix)) (cl--assertion-failed '(not (null defhook-user-prefix)) nil (list (null defhook-user-prefix)) (list))) nil) (let* ((post-hook-action t) (post-defhook-action t) (our-name (symbolp name)) (our-local local) (our-append append) (our-op (cl-assert-rtn op (member op '...) t)) (our-hook-sym (defhook-check-sym-syntax hook-sym "HOOK-NAME")) (our-hook-args hook-args) (tmp-int-spec interactive-spec) (our-int-spec (if (eq tmp-int-spec t) (interactive) tmp-int-spec)) (our-val-hook-name validate-hook-name) (our-eval-after (or eval-after 'simple)) (our-hook-name (cl-assert-rtn our-hook-sym (or (not our-val-hook-name) (string-match-p "-\\(hook\\|function\\|hooks\\|functions\\)$" ...)) t)) (our-func-name (defhook-create-function-name (defhook-check-sym-syntax name "NAME") our-hook-sym)) (our-func-sym (intern our-func-name)) (began-in-hook (member our-func-sym (if (boundp our-hook-sym) (symbol-value our-hook-sym) (set our-hook-sym nil)))) (our-body body) (our-docstring (if (stringp (car our-body)) (progn (setq our-docstring ...)))) (defhook-done-form (list 'defhook-done (list 'quote our-func-sym) (list 'quote our-hook-sym) (list 'quote our-op) (list 'quote began-in-hook) ''nil (list 'quote our-hook-args)))) (if :Comment-Ignore-Test-Code nil (defhook test1 (foo-hook) (message "foo-hook-test1") (message "foo-hook-test1 again")) (defhook test2 (foo-hook) (message "foo-hook-test 2"))) (cond ((eq 'no-op our-op) defhook-done-form) ((eq 'delete our-op) (remove-hook our-hook-sym our-func-sym) defhook-done-form) (t (remove-hook our-hook-sym our-func-sym) (let ((defhook-delayed-done-form ...) (defhook-executed-form ...)) (list 'let (list ...) (list ... ... ...) (list ... ... ... ... ... ... ...))))))))
  (lambda (name (hook-sym &key (op 'add) (interactive-spec t) (append nil) (validate-hook-name t) (eval-after nil) (local nil) (hook-args nil)) &rest body) "Create a hook function and add it to the appropria..." (progn (or (not (null defhook-user-prefix)) (cl--assertion-failed '(not (null defhook-user-prefix)) nil (list (null defhook-user-prefix)) (list))) nil) (let* ((post-hook-action t) (post-defhook-action t) (our-name (symbolp name)) (our-local local) (our-append append) (our-op (cl-assert-rtn op (member op '...) t)) (our-hook-sym (defhook-check-sym-syntax hook-sym "HOOK-NAME")) (our-hook-args hook-args) (tmp-int-spec interactive-spec) (our-int-spec (if (eq tmp-int-spec t) (interactive) tmp-int-spec)) (our-val-hook-name validate-hook-name) (our-eval-after (or eval-after 'simple)) (our-hook-name (cl-assert-rtn our-hook-sym (or (not our-val-hook-name) (string-match-p "-\\(hook\\|function\\|hooks\\|functions\\)$" ...)) t)) (our-func-name (defhook-create-function-name (defhook-check-sym-syntax name "NAME") our-hook-sym)) (our-func-sym (intern our-func-name)) (began-in-hook (member our-func-sym (if (boundp our-hook-sym) (symbol-value our-hook-sym) (set our-hook-sym nil)))) (our-body body) (our-docstring (if (stringp (car our-body)) (progn (setq our-docstring ...)))) (defhook-done-form (list 'defhook-done (list 'quote our-func-sym) (list 'quote our-hook-sym) (list 'quote our-op) (list 'quote began-in-hook) ''nil (list 'quote our-hook-args)))) (if :Comment-Ignore-Test-Code nil (defhook test1 (foo-hook) (message "foo-hook-test1") (message "foo-hook-test1 again")) (defhook test2 (foo-hook) (message "foo-hook-test 2"))) (cond ((eq 'no-op our-op) defhook-done-form) ((eq 'delete our-op) (remove-hook our-hook-sym our-func-sym) defhook-done-form) (t (remove-hook our-hook-sym our-func-sym) (let ((defhook-delayed-done-form ...) (defhook-executed-form ...)) (list 'let (list ...) (list ... ... ...) (list ... ... ... ... ... ... ...)))))))(defhook-emacs-startup-hook-monitor (emacs-startup-hook) "Used by `defhook-startup' to determine if `emacs-s..." (setq defhook-emacs-startup-hook-monitor t))
  (defhook defhook-emacs-startup-hook-monitor (emacs-startup-hook) "Used by `defhook-startup' to determine if `emacs-s..." (setq defhook-emacs-startup-hook-monitor t))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-549255> nil "~/.emacs.d/org-status/defhook.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 31058
  load-with-code-conversion("~/.emacs.d/org-status/defhook.el" "~/.emacs.d/org-status/defhook.el" nil nil)
  load("~/.emacs.d/org-status/defhook.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "~/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1253
  load-with-code-conversion("~/.emacs.d/init.el" "~/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("~/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1fe411c5883d>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1fe411c58851>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Do you have any pointers to fix this?

Comment: Change `defmacro*` to `cl-defmacro`, and add `(require 'cl-lib)` to the file that uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your init file or to the beginning of the old package:

```
(require 'cl)
```

---

Emacs Lisp is a dialect of the [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) language family. [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) is another dialect of Lisp with more features and an official standard. Emacs has a [Common Lisp emulation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/index.html) package which provides features found in Common Lisp but not in Emacs Lisp.

The modern way to [use Common Lisp emulation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Usage.html#Usage) is `(require cl-lib)`. The `cl-lib` package is distributed with Emacs. To avoid name conflicts, the functions and macros in this package have a name that starts with `cl-`. For example, there's a `cl-defmacro` which extends Emacs Lisp's built-in `defmacro` with extra features from Common Lisp, and there's a `cl-reduce` which implements Common Lisp's `reduce` function.

The [old way](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Organization.html#Organization) is `(require 'cl)`. The modern package called `cl` (also distributed with Emacs) uses `cl-lib` to emulate an old `cl` package with different naming conventions: functions and macros that don't exist in Emacs Lisp just have their name from Common Lisp (e.g. `reduce`), and for those that exist in Emacs Lisp, the `cl` package calls its version with an asterisk at the end, e.g. `defmacro*`.

So `defmacro*` is the old-style Common Lisp emulation version of `defmacro`, provided by `cl`.